# Cgroups Memory Related Questions

Tags: linux, rhel, cgroups

**1) Why cgroup is showing more number of tasks than actual number of tasks.?**

Ex :

```
[root@localhost proc]# ps -aux | wc -l
421
[root@localhost proc]# cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/tasks | wc -l
539
```

**2) Why cgroup is showing more memory usage then actual memory usage?**

Ex :

```
[root@localhost memory]# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            11G        425M        9.4G         38M        1.7G         10G
Swap:          2.0G        193M        1.8G
[root@localhost memory]# cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.usage_in_bytes
1596362752
```

Above you can see free is showing used memory as 425M and cgroups is showing around 1.4GB?

Please note that there is only 1 default cgroup, no other cgroups are created

**3) How to calculate correct/proper memory utilization for cgroups?**

Answer (score 1):

1) A multi-threaded process has a single line in `ps aux` output, when each thread is a task. Compare `ps -auxH | wc -l`

Comment: Yes, Its correct, 
I have a question, i have created a thread and when i did "ps -aux" i can see lines for both the thread (Main process and its thread), So does it mean that only kernel's thread is not included in "ps -aux"?

Comment: And Yes Thank You :)
I wish you could help in 3rd question, i have to calculate cgroup's memory status and i am not sure how to achieve that as cgroups's memory is different than "free -h".

Comment: I don't understand what you're calling "kernel thread". `ps -aux` lists only the main thread of each process, `ps -auxH` lists all threads.

Comment: As for your 3rd question, I'm sorry, I know very little about cgroups. (Maybe is shared memory counted several times? That'd be weird though.)